# setTitle and setBackgroundImage not working for UIButton nested within UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have some code like this:

```
- (void)updateUI {
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.oneDimensionalArrayContainingCardButtons) {
        int cardButtonIndex = [self.oneDimensionalArrayContainingCardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton];

        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:cardButtonIndex];
        [cardButton setTitle:[self titleForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cardButton setBackgroundImage:[self backgroundImageForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isMatched;
        self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];
    }
}


- (NSString *)titleForCard:(Card *)card
{
    NSString *ret =  card.isChosen ? card.contents : @"";
    NSLog(ret);
    return ret;
}

- (UIImage *)backgroundImageForCard:(Card *)card   {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:card.isChosen ? @"cardback" : @"cardfront"];
}
```

and a UI that looks like this:

[image: my UI]

When I click on the a card below, I get set the clicked card to chosen and update the UI. I can see by watching the logs that the contents is being set logged out as `ret` meaning I am passing in a non-empty NSString to `cardButton setTitle`.

The problem is, the background image does not change and the title does not appear to get set.

The `cardButton.enabled` property does appear to get set as expected.

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

What is 'Card'? Is it a custom button that extends from UIButton? In that case the issue might be with Card rather the string you pass to it.

Comment: Card is a model class, extends NSObject

Answer (score 0):

SetTitleColor or Add backgroundColor Red/Orange to cardButton.titelLabel so that you will come to know Button's titleLable is hiding somewhere or not. If it doesnt show titleLabel then You should check titleLable's frame.